# Implementing data hiding access specifiers in C language

Tags: c, oop

Is there is a way to implement access specifiers like "private", "protected" in C language. I came across solutions in the internet about using "static" and "ifdefs" for making a function available only inside certain other functions.

Apart from these, is there any C implementation equivalent of using private and protected access specifiers in C++ classes?

Comment: C is turing complete, so you should be able to. Question is if it is worth the effort and if the code will still be maintainable. If you want C++, use C++, not C. They are different languages. (Hell, why does no one ask for inline-Assembler in SQL?)

Comment: @Olaf It is completely reasonable to do OOP in C, and for any complex C project, I'd say it's the best approach. Downside is, a lot more boilerplate code is needed, and compiler is unable to detect part of errors a C++ compiler would detect or not allow at all for equivalent code. Also C++ style RAII is unavailable. The bonus is, programmer has complete control over what happens in their code, there's no implicit code executon (no exceptions or implicit constructors and destructors), and vtable's are under direct control of programmer too.

Comment: @hyde: OOP is not just how C++ implements it. And information hiding is not a vital aspect of OOP (see other languages, e.g. Python which is full OOP - as opposed to the partial OOP in C++ or Java). Where do I point out one cannot or should not do OOP in C? Please don't read semantics which are not stated! But it should be clear that there is some point where using a language which supports a specific feature directly is better than riding a horse beyond (its) death.

Comment: @Olaf So, you're actually arguing against trying to duplicate C++ constructs and idioms *directly* in C? With that, I agree.

Comment: @Olaf Turing completeness has nothing to do with sugary language features.

Comment: @hyde: I argue against trying to implement C++ features in C with the sledegehammer. And to bloat C code beyond maintainability (that also applies to macros btw.). If you see my history, you might notive I'm very well a strong supporter of C against C++ **where reasonable**. OP clearly goes beyond that (not that I never did; it is a permanent temptation).

Comment: @immibis: OP asks about implementation, not sugar. But maybe I read this wrong and he really wants to implement it **in the compiler itself**.

Comment: @Olaf Access specifiers are sugar by definition - they are language constructs that do not allow the program to do anything it couldn't do before.

Comment: @immibis: Hsving them in the language itself is, but not their functionality. It allows the program to restrict access to specific modules at a finer-than-module grain. (Not that I see much sense in how C++ supports that)

Comment: @Olaf Which has nothing to do with the Turing-completeness of the language. That's like saying you can have automatic semicolon insertion in Brainfuck because it's Turing-complete.

Comment: @immibis: It very well does, as that implies that you **can implement** this in C. Just possibly not the way OP  might think of. With an interpreter being the most complex way. (Which could also insert the semicolons on random basis).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C does not have user definable name spaces or access specifiers. Since you exclude (ab)use of preprocessor, the only way to get compiler error trying to access private parts of "classes" is to not have a .h file which exposes "private" stuff. They can still be put into "private" separate .h files (included by module's or library's own .c files, but not meant to be included from application code), or hidden behind `#ifdef`s (requiring special define to activate the "private" parts).

One common way to hide things is to use opaque structs AKA opaque pointers. For that approach, the code outside a module or library only has pointer to a struct, but no struct definition. And then it uses functions offered by the module to get an instance, access it, and finally release it.

With this approach, you easily get public interface: the functions you provide in the public .h file, as well as any public support structs which have definition there. The private interface is the code where the full struct definition is visible, and any functions which are not in the public .h file.

Protected access implies inheritance, which usually works very differently from C++, when implemented with C by hand, and which is too broad a subject to cover in this answer. The closest thing to this would probably be to have several .h files, which provide several levels of "public" access, and then it is responsibility of the programmer to not get into problems with them.

The good thing about this approach is, other code using the module does not need to be modified (or even recompiled), if struct is changed. Often struct might even be an union, and then the module's functions would branch based on the actual type, all invisibe from the code using it. Another good thing is, the module can control creation of structs, so it could for example have a pool of structs and avoid using heap, all invisible to the application code. One downside is, you can't have inline functions (because the inline function body in .h file would need the struct definition, which we are trying to hide here), which prevents some nice compiler optimizations in cases where performance is a concern.

Example (untested code written for this answer):

module.h:

```
// ...other standard header file stuff ...

// forward declaration of struct
struct module_data;

// "constructor" function
struct module_data *module_initialize_data(int value);

// modification function
int module_update_data(struct module_data *data, int adjust);

// "destructor" function
void module_release(struct module_data *data);
```

module.c

```
#include "module.h"

// struct definition only in the .c file
struct module_data {
   int value;
};

struct module_data *module_initialize_data(int value) {
    struct module_data *data = malloc(sizeof(*data));
    data->value = value;
    return data;
}

int module_update_data(struct module_data *data, int adjust) {
    data->value += adjust;
    return data->value;
}

void module_release(struct module_data *data) {
    free(data);
}
```

---

Relevant Wikipedia links for reference:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type

Comment: C very well has namespaces! It just has no user-defined namespaces. Your approach does not allow what OP asks for. It would be much more complicated (and nonsense) to implement that.

Comment: @Olaf Do you mean scopes, or what?

Comment: I can tell namespaces and scope well apart. Read the standard. (it also differentiates betwee scope and name space).

Comment: Added words "user definable" to be more accurate (also other edits).

Comment: Tht does not change the rest of my critique.

Comment: @Olaf It's unclear what the OP is actually asking, because question does not say what it means by "equivalent". I mean, in C++ the keywords basically just cause compiler errors, if class members are used from wrong places. Is that all that OP wants? Then some empty macros and hacking a "lint" tool to complain about invalid use would be a decent way...

Answer (score 5):

C does not have access specifiers. The only way to hide something from your callers is to not provide its declaration in the header.

You can make it static in the translation unit:

myapi.h

```
extern int visibleVariable;
void visibleFunction();
```

myapi.c

```
int visibleVariable;
static int invisibleVariable;
void visibleFunction() {
    ...
}
static void invisibleFunction() {
    ...
}
```

You can also hide the definition of a `struct` by placing it in the implementation file. This way all fields of your struct would be private to the translation unit. The drawback to this approach is that the users of your API would be unable to declare variables of your `struct`'s type, so they would need to deal with your `struct` through pointers.

C has no concept of inheritance, hence there is no equivalent of `protected` access.

Comment: Hmm, `int i;` in the implementation is also static. You mean `static`. But none seems actually what OP wants.

Comment: @Olaf It seems like this is part of what OP wants, he just wants more.

Comment: He seems to want a single `struct` with partially invisible members. Funny enough, as C++ does not really hiden them, just makes them harder to reach.

Comment: @hyde I restructured the sentence so that it no longer implies that `static` is the only way to go. Thanks!